# How to run function on the deepest level only in a nested list?

Tags: r, list, algorithm

Given a nested list for example as below

```
lst <- list(
    1,
    list(list(c(4, 5, 4)), list(c(6, 7))),
    list(c(2, 3, 3)),
    list(list(c(5, 5, 6)), list(c(7, 7, 7)))
)

> str(lst)
List of 4
 $ : num 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:3] 4 5 4
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:2] 6 7
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:3] 2 3 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:3] 5 5 6
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:3] 7 7 7
```

Let's say its deepest level is 3, e.g., depths of vectors `4 5 4`, `6 7`, `5 5 6` and `7 7 7` in `lst`.

I am wondering if there is a way that only runs a certain function over those deepest levels, while other levels are untouched. For example, if the the function is `unique`, then my expected output is

```
lstout <- list(
    1,
    list(list(c(4, 5)),list(c(6,7))),
    list(c(2, 3, 3)),
    list(list(c(5, 6)), list(7))
)

> str(lstout)
List of 4
 $ : num 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:2] 4 5
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:2] 6 7
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:3] 2 3 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:2] 5 6
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num 7
```

It seems `rapply` cannot run the function selectively only on the deepest level. I have no clue how to make it.

Any *base R* idea or solution would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can recursively descend `lst` to find the maximum depth and then use that to recursively descend again applying `unique` only at the maximum depth.  No packages are used.

```
maxDepth <- function(x, depth = 0) {
   if (is.list(x)) max(sapply(x, maxDepth, depth+1))
   else depth
}

lstUnique <- function(x, depth = maxDepth(x)) {
  if (depth == 0) unique(x)
  else if (is.list(x)) lapply(x, lstUnique, depth-1)
  else x
}

lstUnique(lst)
```

### Variation using rapply

A variation of the above is to recursively add a class to each leaf equal to its depth.  Then we can use `rapply` three times.  First use `rapply` to extract the classes and take the maximum to find the maximum depth. second use `rapply` to apply `unique` on just the nodes having the maximum depth class. Third, remove any remaining classes that were not removed by `unique` because the node was not at maximum depth.  (The third `rapply`, i.e. the last line of code below, could be omitted if it is ok to leave some leaves with the classes we added.)

```
addDepth <- function(x, depth = 0) {
  if (is.list(x)) lapply(x, addDepth, depth+1)
  else structure(x, class = format(depth))
}
lst2 <- addDepth(lst)

mx <- max(as.numeric(rapply(lst2, class))) # max depth
lst3 <- rapply(lst2, unique, classes = format(mx), how = "replace")
rapply(lst3, as.vector, how = "replace")
```

### Note on rapply

Note that if you alternately wanted to run unique on all leaves rather than just on the maximum depth leaves then `rapply` in base R would work.

```
rapply(lst, unique, how = "replace")
```

### data.tree

This alternative does require the use of a package.  First we create a data.tree `dt` and then traverse it applying unique to the nodes that satisfy the filterFun.

```
library(data.tree)

dt <- as.Node(lst)
dt$Do(function(x) x$"1" <- unique(x$"1"), 
  filterFun = function(x) x$level == dt$height)
print(dt, "1")
```

### rrapply

The rrapply package provides an enhancement to rapply which can also pass a position vector whose length equals the depth so we can use it first to calculate the maximum depth mx and then again to apply unique only at that depth. (Have updated `rrapply` call to use how = "unlist" as opposed to applying unlist afterwards as per suggestion in comments.)

```
library(rrapply)

mx <- max(rrapply(lst, f = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos), how = "unlist"))
uniq_mx <- function(x, .xpos) if (length(.xpos) == mx) unique(x) else x
rrapply(lst, is.numeric, uniq_mx)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot. Sorry that I had a typo in my question, now it is fixed

Comment: in the definition of `mx` in the `rrapply`-approach, the unlisting can also be done with the `rrapply` call using: `max(rrapply(lst, f = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos), how = "unlist"))`

Comment: Thanks. Have made that change.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot think of a `base R` option, but with `purrr`, you can a get close solution:

```
modify_depth(lst, 3, unique, .ragged = TRUE)

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 4 5


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 6 7



[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 3


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[[4]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 5 6


[[4]][[2]]
[[4]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1! If I don't know what is the max depth of the nested list, is it possible to get it via package `purrr`? I am curious if there is way in base R way that can automatically read the max depth and run the function there. I am now still learning R, so I prefer base R solution :)

Comment: In `purrr`, you have the function `vec_depth()` to determine the depth.